# This error keeps appearing: ! Package inputenc Error:Keyboard character used is undefined in inputencoding ansinew

Tags: errors, input-encodings

I have been working on this document without problem, but now everytime I compile it, this message appears:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `ansinew'.
```

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,10pt]{report}


\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %francais, polish, spanish, ...
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ansinew]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{a4wide} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{longtable} 
\begin{document}

\pagestyle{empty} 

\title{INFORME ETAPA I: 
DIAGNÓSTICO DE LA SITUACIÓN ACTUAL}

\author{CONTRATO No. LCC-MPORTO-2016-003}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
some text here
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents 
\cleardoublepage 
\pagestyle{plain} 

%%Chapters%%

%\include{./capitulos/parte 1} 

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de Figuras}
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Índice de Cuadros}
\listoftables

\appendix


\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably, you have changed the editor you use to edit the source file, switching from one which used the `ansinew` encoding to another that uses a different encoding (most likely, `utf8`).  Please add information concerning hte editors you have been using previously, and the one you are using now.

Comment: really you should not use `ansinew` for new documents it was never a standard encoding (and not defined by ANSI) it was just a weirdly named microsoft code page. For new documents you should use utf-8 or (if you want an 8-bit encoding) latin1. Most likely the error is because yor editor has saved yout file in latin1 or utf-8 and not the microsoft "ansinew" encoding.

Answer (score 1):

As posted your code is in UTF-8 (as the whole website is UTF-8) and so the accented letters in the title are not understood, as LaTeX is expecting `ansinew`

```
! Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined
(inputenc)                in inputencoding `ansinew'.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.2 ...nc@undefined@ {ansinew}ndice de Figuras}{3}

?
```

The error comes from the `Í` when read back for the table of contents.

deleting the corrupt `.toc` file then specifing

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

allows the document to run without error

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution (erased the .toc document and specified UTF-8 package) but not it takes forever to compile, and then I get new error messages like this: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode cha ÓS (U+66) (inputenc) not set up for use with Latex.